# How to add a facebook glyphicon to rails link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add a glyph-icon to my Facebook link_to in ruby on rails but when I try it doesn't show up any idea on how to do this?

This is the what I have attempted:

```
<li> 
  <i class= "fa fa-facebook"></i>
  <%= link_to "Facebook", '/facebook' %>
</li>
```

any help is greatly appreciated..thank you

Comment: More background info, please. It seems you are using Font Awesome. Do you use a gem to get the font? Which gem, and have you followed install directions of the gem? What version of Rails?

Comment: if you using bootstrap 4, it's not supported anymore,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about:

```
<li> 
  <%= link_to '/facebook' do %>
    Facebook // delete if you don't need text
    <i class= "fa fa-facebook"></i>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= link_to '/facebook' do %>
    <i class= "fa fa-facebook"></i>
 <% end %>
```